# jQuery: Change Image Width on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two images side-by-side. When the user hovers over an image, it should expand.

### HTML:

```
<a href="#"><div id="skinny"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="room9"></div></a>
```

### jQuery:

```
$('#skinny').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: '220px'}, 'fast');
    $('#room9').animate({width: '80px'}, 'fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({width:'150px'},'fast');
    $('#room9').animate({width: '150px'}, 'fast');
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/G4q4q/

It "works" with the left image, but I couldn't get it to work with the right. My current method is inefficient, so if you have any suggestions to optimize it, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sure there's heaps of plugins out there doing exactly what you want, [zaccordion](http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/) for example

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want any plugins?

Comment: @Aaron Did you purposefully not bind any hover events to the `#room9` element?

Comment: @Derek, the plugin I provided does exactly what the example site he provided does. Exactly the same. Personally, I don't like reinventing the wheel when someone else has done all the hard work. Each to their own..

Comment: @Jonathan, I didn't add a hover event because it was not working right. I couldn't expand the image and shrink the left one down.

Comment: @Christian, I understand I could use a plug-in, but I'd like to learn how they did it.

Comment: @Aaron I just copied your code and replaced the `id` values: http://jsfiddle.net/G4q4q/6/ This is not what you were looking for?

Comment: @Jonathan, I was able to do this, but the "stutter" it creates is why I turned to StackOverflow. Especially since my method of resizing the images is probably the reason for this choppiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well I've made a very crude example that doesn't allow for expansion/multiple images, but you should get the idea. To `clip` elements in CSS, just just `overflow: hidden`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G4q4q/10/

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <a href="#" id="skinny">
        <img class="image" src="http://www.theexoticvet.com/images/content_1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="room9">
        <img class="image" src="http://www.theexoticvet.com/images/content_2.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

​Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width: '80%'}, 'fast')
        $('a').not(this).stop().animate({width: '20%'}, 'fast');
    }, function() {
        $('a').stop().animate({width:'50%'},'fast');
    });
});
```

​
Edit notes: I edited this to make it a little better than my first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time making a more general method for this - so at least have a look at this no matter you use it or not. I know Christian will damn me for reinventing the wheel, but still, I started long before he wrote the comment...and by the way, you wanted to learn how those things work right? For that, I created this plugin (Christian damns me now) here: http://jsfiddle.net/hHzkS/

I've commented it...if any doubt ask in the comments...

Comment: HELLO??? Did someone at least see this? No comments, no votes (up/down)...._no nothing_ !